# Any trick to disconnecting old / reconnecting new reinforced vinyl tubing from the push-lock connectors, or does it have to be cut off?

Tags: hose, vinyl, pushfit

I am trying to disconnect the reinforced vinyl tubing from the push-lock connectors on my masonry saw, in order to determine the ID.  OD is 15mm.  I am unable to twist it off by hand after loosening the  clamp because the connector itself spins separately from push-fit piece that fits inside the tube. Does it have to be cut off?

[image: hose connector]

Comment: Do you need to reuse the hose?

Comment: I was thinking I needed to preserve it in case a replacement would not be available for several days  Most of the independently owned hardware stores in the area have shut their doors, and the one near me that is still open doesn't keep much stock on the shelves, but you can order online from the regional warehouse and pick the item up at the store.  That sometimes takes a week or two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heat usually helps.

Hot water, wife's blow dryer, hot air gun.

You want it warm, not hot enough to cook meat/your fingers.

Cutting needs to be done carefully, to prevent nicking of the barb.

Comment: Amazing what a little bit of heat can do. Slipped right off, when I couldn't budge it at all when it was cold using all my might.

Comment: @TR888   I must admit that most of the time, the handy dandy knife in the pocket won out over the non handy heat.

Comment: I'm uncertain about the sizing. McMaster has both metric and imperial sizing charts and filtering options. Is tubing manufactured to the metric size and then for the US given a *nominal* imperial size like 3/8 inch ID? Is 3/8 a 9.5mm ID or  a 10mm ID?

Answer (score 1):

Agree that heat would absolutely work, except you aren’t going to get the exact id if you’re looking at the flared part at the end.

Besides, if the whole hose is being replaced, it’s quicker to cut it off.

Maybe save the heating effort for reassembly if it proves difficult.

Comment: I needed to use it today with a bit of flashing tape that doesn't really work, though at least it stops the geyser.  Would I be able to measure the wall thickness, or does that get compressed at the flare end?

Comment: I suspect that the wall thickness wouldn’t vary by much, if at all.